# Jquery $.post to get data back in JSON format, can't iterate data properly?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm building a web calendar application and I'm trying to add a feature that checks the db before sending a form to see if we can add the calendar event or not.

Right now I have this script that try to get the response from a PHP file:

```
// send form data using ajax requests
$.post(
    "addons/validate_event.php", 
    $("#modif_inventaire").serialize(), 
    function(response){      

        if (response) {

            var htmlresponse = "";

            $.each(response, function(key, value) { 
              htmlresponse += key + ': ' + value; 
            });

            alert(response)
            alert(htmlresponse)
        }
    }
);
```

The response "addons/validate_event.php" will look like this: `{}` (empty == success) or like this:

```
{"20120106":[1300,1430,1510,"1600"],"20120107":["0900",1000,"1100","1200","1300","1400","1500"]}
```

Basically, I have a PHP script that check if we can add the event, if so, it returns an `empty` array. Otherwise, it returns an array containing `dates` in the format `yyyymmdd` and each date has an array of available `hours` in this format `hhmm`.

But my problem is that when i try to iterate the array, `alert(response)` gives me the php answer `{"20120106":[1300,143 ....` but `alert(htmlresponse)` gives me this:

`0: {1: "2: 23: 04: 15: 26: 07: 18: 09: 310: "11: :12: [13: "14: 015: 916: 017: 018: "19: ,20: 121: 022: 423: 024: ,25: "26: 127: 128: 029: 030: "31: ,32: 133: 034: 235: 036: ,37: 138: 139: 040: 541: ,42: 143: 044: 245: 546: ,47: 148: 149: 150: 051: ,52: 153: 054: 355: 056: ,57: 158: 159: 160: 561: ,62: 163: 064: 365: 566: ,67:......`

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $.get/$.post to parse the JSON response automatically, you'll need to pass in 'json' as the fourth argument, as the following:

```
// send form data using ajax requests
$.post(
    "addons/validate_event.php", 
    $("#modif_inventaire").serialize(), 
    function(response){      

        if (response) {

            var htmlresponse = "";

            $.each(response, function(key, value) { 
              htmlresponse += key + ': ' + value; 
            });

            alert(response)
            alert(htmlresponse)
        }
     }, 'json' // this argument is needed so jquery will treat response as JSON object and not text
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with you callback json data. I have one good habit. Hoping helpful to you.
Step1: `$.trim(data);`
Step2:`var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`
Step3: Processing your code.